# Find maximum value of values in hash where key value in array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a hash where I'm trying to find the maximum value of a key-value pair only but only if the key exists in an external array.

E.g.

```
Available_domains = ["A", "B"]

object = {
A: 1,
B: 2,
C: 3
}
```

Should return 2, since I'm only computing for keys that are found in available_domains array. Wondering what the best way to do that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way is this:

```
AvailableDomains.map { |k| object[k.to_sym] }.max
```

Here's another way to do it:

```
object.with_indifferent_access.values_at(*AvailableDomains).max
```

If the array contained symbols, the with_indifferent_access would be unnecessary, but it's used here so that the Array's strings can match the hash's symbol keys.

Comment: What if `Available_domains = ["A", "B", "D"]`?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to filter the object to just the keys that are in the array, then select the max from that:

```
options = object.select{ |key, value| Available_domains.include?(key.to_s)}
options.max_by{|key, value| value}
```

In one line:

```
object.select{ |key, value| Available_domains.include?(key.to_s)}.max_by{|key, value| value}
```

Comment: I suggest you only give the "In one line" answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Available_domains = ["A", "B", "D"]
object = { A: 1, B: 2, C: 3 }

object.values_at(*Available_domains.map(&:to_sym)).compact.max
  #=> 2
```

The steps:

```
a = Available_domains.map(&:to_sym)
  #=> [:A, :B, :D] 
b = object.values_at(*a)
  #=> [1, 2, nil] 
c = b.compact
  #=> [1, 2] 
c.max
  #=> 2
```

If

```
Available_domains = ["D", "E"]
```

then

```
object.values_at(*Available_domains.map(&:to_sym)).compact.max.nil?
  #=> true
```